# Does LINQ have any easy/elegant way to take the first element and put it at the end?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

Or should I say, skip the first element and come back to it at the end.

e.g. say I have

```
int[] arr = { 2, 4, 3, 9, 1, 0 };
```

and want to iterate through it like

```
{ 4, 3, 9, 1, 0, 2 }
```

I know one way would be like

```
foreach(int i in arr.Skip(1).Append(new int[] { arr.First() }))
```

which is why I'm asking whether there's a better looking and/or more efficient way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only slightly cleaner than what you've got:

```
foreach(int i in arr.Skip(1).Concat(arr.Take(1)))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way. (not cleaner tho)

```
Enumerable.Range(1, arr.Length)
          .Select(x => arr[x%arr.Length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hold it into a new collection, like a list, since it will be more ckear what I am doing when somebody else will read my code  (if ever). A list is well optimized for this kind of behavior:

```
var list = arr.ToList();
list.Add(list.ElemntAt(0));
list.RemoveAt(0);
```

Then you can iterate the list, and it is more verbose to do it this way rather than using a Linq query, which can solve this problem, but it may not be so easy to read.